# Can i control ALL Camera/Microphone associated recordings (sounds, images, streams, etc) for ANY APPs using the devices on IOS and Android OS's?

Tags: android, ios, security, video, photos

The idea is that we want to process these images, videos, audio recordings for security requirements at a server BEFORE releasing them back to the user

Comment: Why don't you describe the actual problem you are trying solve, before starting with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that this can be achieved via any legal way.
You want to collect all user data which are not even created using your app.

If a user grants the permission to your app then "Yes". 
Your app can have the permissions accordingly which the user needs to agree before installing the app.
Your app now has access to images/video/sounds from user machine and you can sync it back to your server.

I personally will not install any such app.

Comment: Before you start jumping to conclusions, this is an app for a company issued device solely for work purposes NOT A PERSONAL phone, etc and it is absolutely legal, so please use the creative part of your mind or ask questions before assuming nefarious designs.

Additionally for the technical part the question asks can photos etc be reviewed "BEFORE releasing" back to User, which is not clear from your answer.

Comment: @CustosMortem: "it is absolutely legal" -- I would strongly encourage you to retain personal legal counsel on this.

Comment: Our counsel assures us "it is absolutely legal" - could you help us and tell us why this is not the case? Thx.

Comment: @CommonsWare Our counsel assures us "it is absolutely legal" - could you help us and tell us why this is not the case? Thx.

Comment: @CustosMortem: I simply advised that you get a **personal** attorney to advise you on your course of action. Corporate counsel is there for the business, not you as an individual.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I don't understand why i would need a personal attorney? what are you implying exactly?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, no, you cannot do this. Through device admin APIs, you can enact policies that block the camera from use (I don't recall an equivalent option for the microphone). But given that the camera and microphone are available to apps, you have no way of intercepting them, processing them, and somehow seamlessly getting that data back to the apps that had requested the microphone and camera. Similarly, you have no guaranteed way of getting at "recordings", for the simple reason that these apps do not have to create files at all, let alone ones that you have access to.

You are welcome to create a custom ROM that contains this ..."feature"... and try to convince users to replace their Android installation with your ROM.

Comment: Thanks, are you implying that  a "device driver" type code must be written to do this?

Comment: @CustosMortem: I do not know the exact details of how such a custom ROM would be implemented that contains your desired ability. However, that ROM contains everything that sits between the hardware and the app. By definition, it can alter the content silently, such as replacing all photos taken by the camera with pictures of Vladimir Putin. Your plan of doing network I/O in this process may cause apps to fail, just because there is unexpected latency.